# my json show only single image and text

Tags: android

my json file show only single image not show all images and text below is my code  ths is my screen shot

[image]

and i want to make like this

[image]

tell me whats wrong in my code?  why its not show all three images and textview?????

```
 {
    "worldpopulation": [{
            "rank": 1,
            "name": "BREAKFAST",
            "url": "http://niel986.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/fast-food.jpg"
        }, {
            "rank": 2,
            "name2": "LUNCH ",
            "url2": "http://www.bubblews.com/assets/images/news/1107772406_1370520219.gif"
        }, {
            "rank": 3,
            "name3": "SUPPER",
            "url3": "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_JU_j7jj5TjU/TSBQKRukf1I/AAAAAAAAAs8/X1w5_z6pjwQ / s1600 / chicken - biryani.jpg "
        }
    ]
 }
```

---

```
    ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);

    TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

    ImageView img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2);

    TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);

    ImageView img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img3);

    TextView txt3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt3);

    cla3 = new CategoryListAdapter3(thirdstep.this);

    MenuSelect = Utils.MenuSelect;

     try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 
 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(MenuSelect);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new   
 InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            str += line;
        }


            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");

              for ( int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++ )
                {
                    JSONObject jsonOrder = (JSONObject)data.get(i);
                    int rabk = jsonOrder.getInt("rank");
                    String name = jsonOrder.getString("name");
                    String url1 = jsonOrder.getString("url");


                    txt1.setText(name);
                     Bitmap bitmap = 
   BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url1).getContent());
                 img1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



                 int rabk2 = jsonOrder.getInt("rank2");
                    String name2 = jsonOrder.getString("name2");
                    String url2 = jsonOrder.getString("url2");


                    txt2.setText(name2);
                     Bitmap bitmap2 = 
     BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url2).getContent());
                 img2.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);

                 int rabk3 = jsonOrder.getInt("rank3");
                    String name3 = jsonOrder.getString("name3");
                    String url3 = jsonOrder.getString("url3");


                    txt3.setText(name3);
                     Bitmap bitmap3 = 
      BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url3).getContent());
                 img3.setImageBitmap(bitmap3);



                }
```

below is my xml code:

```
 <LinearLayout 

 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:background="@drawable/imagebgborder"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
  </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/img3"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txt3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
 </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access to some keys in your json that don't exist like "rank2" and "rank3".
So basically in every cycle you assign a new value but just to the first textview and imageview.
That also why it's the last vale the one that is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have different hard coded variable names (i.e. url1, url2, url3) you will need to remove the for loop and manually select each array item.
Replace your for loop above with the following code:

```
                JSONObject jsonOrder = (JSONObject)data.get(0);
                int rabk = jsonOrder.getInt("rank");
                String name = jsonOrder.getString("name");
                String url1 = jsonOrder.getString("url");


                txt1.setText(name);
                 Bitmap bitmap = 
BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url1).getContent());
             img1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


JSONObject jsonOrder = (JSONObject)data.get(1);
             int rabk2 = jsonOrder.getInt("rank2");
                String name2 = jsonOrder.getString("name2");
                String url2 = jsonOrder.getString("url2");


                txt2.setText(name2);
                 Bitmap bitmap2 = 
 BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url2).getContent());
             img2.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);



JSONObject jsonOrder = (JSONObject)data.get(2);


             int rabk3 = jsonOrder.getInt("rank3");
                String name3 = jsonOrder.getString("name3");
                String url3 = jsonOrder.getString("url3");


                txt3.setText(name3);
                 Bitmap bitmap3 = 
  BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url3).getContent());
             img3.setImageBitmap(bitmap3);
```